# What possibilities are there for an xarray based database?

Tags: python, database, python-xarray

I am working a lot with geospatial data in python (mainly weather forecasts)  and for this issue I am doing a lot of stuff with `xarray` .

`xarray` supports conversion into hdf/netcdf files which is fine if you want to store the data with no requirements to the speed to get access again. What I am looking for is a database for fast access to single data points of the xarray to build up a restful WEB-API. Is there an easy way to store an xarray to such a database?

Note: A typical `xarray.DataArray` contains an array of values, coordinates like latitude, longitude and timstamps. The horizontal dimension of the values equals to the grid formed by latitude and longitude and the third dimension equals to the length timestamps in the `xarray.DataArray`

Answer (score 4):

I would consider two options.

If you have a distributed filesystem infrastructure you could leverage that by creating netcdf files with chunks of the data, aggregate the data using [ncml](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/current/ncml/) and publishing the dataset in an [ERDDAP](https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/index.html) server. Taking this path you could have a decent access speed, and the API rest to access the data, in multiple formats (.nc,.mat,csv,json,etc), also you could pull the data directly to your xarray workflows.

I would also explore the possibility of using the [zarr](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#zarr) format to store your data, this one is different from netcdf, the data is stored in chunks in a folder structure, it also supports concurrent access, and with this format you could [store the data with cloud providers](https://pangeo.io/data.html#data-in-the-cloud) (google, aws), using key,value storage. You can also leverage your workflows using [dask](https://dask.org/) by parallelizing your analysis.

If the plan is to build a custom API Rest, have a look at [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

Comment: Just to extend @Favo's answer a bit. Zarr can also use a number of database backends such as DBM, Redis, MongoDB, and LMDB. More on that here: https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be v exciting. You could store your data in its native format, and potentially push some reduce computations down to the database.

There was an issue about [SciDB](https://www.paradigm4.com/) at some point - i.e. could we make that into an xarray backend.

I also see [TileDB](https://tiledb.io/) has some overlapping goals.

But nothing exists now - you can use one of the flat formats you suggested, or build an array from tabular data from a traditional database.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.